# Setting FilePath and FileName in vba

Tags: excel, vba, filenames, filepath

Ok so I think I have gotten confused on how to do this and maybe I am doing something obviously wrong?

Here is my code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook, wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet

    filelocation1 = "C:\Users\Public\Desktop_" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy") & "Production.xls"
    Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("Production")
    Set wbO = Workbooks.Add
    With wbO
        Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("Sheet1")
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=filelocation1 '******
        wsI.Range("A1:C100").Copy
        wsO.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With
```

However at the asterisked line I get a run time error (included as image). I think it's because I am saving the file incorrectly...but I thought this was correct? Is it because I am using a file path instead of a file name? Would I need ot add at the end of the path "Name".xls? Or do I need to separate file name and file path?

Thanks in advance :)

[image]

EDIT: Now Things are working however, the file is being dumped in "C:\Users\Public"  location with DESKTOP added to the name (instead of "C:\Users\Public\Desktop" . I have tried all sorts of stuff trying to route it to the correct location, like adding a "_" at the end as well as other tricks that have not worked.

How do i fix this?

SOLVED :

```
filelocation1 = "C:\Users\Public\Desktop" & "\" &  Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy") _ 
& "Production.xls"
```

Comment: "Is it because I am using a file path instead of a file name? Would I need ot add at the end of the path 'Name'.xls?"  This is correct.  You must include a filename.

Comment: @tigeravatar Am I able to use the TODAY() function in the middle of that? I would have to do something like "path/x/x/" & TODAY() & ".xls" ?

Comment: yes if you convert it to a string

Comment: @Aranzi - If someone wants to restrict their response to a 'drive-by' answer in the form of a comment, imho they have no recourse when someone offers a similar action in the form of a legitimate 'answer'.

Comment: Agreed; please don't take my comments as any way malicious. I'm just saying (for Jordan Biddlecombe's benefit as much as yours) that one shouldn't disparage a fairly new user's effort if they haven't made the same themselves. Peace out. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax error i believe

I tend to use something like

```
dim filelocation as string
dim fileext as string
dim filestring as string
```

Then use "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\" as your file location and set the fileext as whatever you like e.g. if you wanted to say type you own file name into a text box then `fileext = textbox.text` then it's a case of `filestring = filelocation & fileext`. This sort of method allows you flexibility if you play around with it

Answer (score 4):

You need to include the file name in the file path e.g. `"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Name.xls"`

Comment: I would add that it a better practice to exclude the file extension and allow the `FileFormat:=56` to determine that from the [XlFileFormat Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx). (**56** being xlExcel8).